How do I get a visible border on File Explorer in Windows Server 2019
File Explorer on Windows Server 2019 has no visible indicator for its upper boundary. This means that against another window with white background, I cannot tell where the File Explorer window actually ends, and so it is difficult to know where to click to move File Explorer.
How do I configure Windows to show a border around File Explorer, particularly the top border?


To display windows with border:

Press the Windows key, type Color settings and press Enter.
In the Colors window scroll to the bottom.
Check Title bars and window borders.

